# Retrieve ALL header data with urllib

Tags: python, http-headers, urllib

I've scraped many websites and have often wondered why the response headers displayed in Firebug and the response headers returned by `urllib.urlopen(url).info()` are often different in that Firebug reports MORE headers.

I encountered an interesting one today. I'm scraping a website by following a "search url" that fully loads (returns a 200 status code) before redirecting to a final page. The easiest way to perform the scrape would be to return the `Location` response header and make another request. However, that particular header is absent when I run 'urllib.urlopen(url).info().

Here is the difference:

Firebug headers:

```
Cache-Control : no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection : keep-alive
Content-Encoding : gzip
Content-Length : 2433
Content-Type : text/html
Date : Fri, 05 Oct 2012 15:59:31 GMT
Expires : Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location : /catalog/display/1292/index.html
Pragma : no-cache
Server : Apache/2.0.55
Set-Cookie : PHPSESSID=9b99dd9a4afb0ef0ca267b853265b540; path=/
Vary : Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By : PHP/4.4.0
```

Headers returned by my code:

```
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2012 17:16:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.55
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.0
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=39ccc547fc407daab21d3c83451d9a04; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

Here's my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import scrape_tools


tools = scrape_tools.tool_box()
db = tools.db_connect()

cursor = db.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT data FROM table WHERE variable = 'Constant' ORDER BY data")

for row in cursor:
    url = 'http://www.website.com/search/' + row['data']    
    headers = {
            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language' : 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
            'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'Host' : 'www.website.com',
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'
            }
    post_params = {
                'query' : row['data'],
                'searchtype' : 'products'
                }
    post_args = urllib.urlencode(post_params)
    soup = tools.request(url, post_args, headers)

    print tools.get_headers(url, post_args, headers)
```

Please note: `scrape_tools` is a module I wrote myself. The code contained in the module to retrieve headers is (basically) as follows:

```
class tool_box:
    def get_headers(self, url, post, headers):
        file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url, post, headers)
        return file_pointer.info()
```

Is there a reason for the discrepancy? Am I making a silly mistake in my code? How can I retrieve the missing header data? I'm fairly new to Python, so please forgive any dumb errors.

Thanks in advance. Any advice is much appreciated!

Also...Sorry about the wall of code =\

Comment: BS is for parsing HTML/XML, not HTTP headers.

Comment: My goal isn't to parse HTTP headers with BS. My question is how to retrieve the headers to continue with my scrape and parse HTML...

Comment: What are the status codes for the two responses?

Comment: I just noticed you already observed a redirect and mentioned it, I somehow missed that even though I read the question several times :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting the same kind of response for the two requests. For example, the response to the Firefox request contains a `Location:` header, so it's probably a `302 Moved temporarily` or a `301`. Those don't contain any actual body data, but instead cause your Firefox to issue a second request to the URL in the `Location:` header (urllib doesn't do that).

The Firefox response also uses `Connection : keep-alive` while the urllib request got answered with `Connection: close`.

Also, the Firefox response is gzipped (`Content-Encoding : gzip`), while the urllib one is not. That's probably because your Firefox sends a `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header with its request.

Don't rely on Firebug to tell you HTTP headers (even though it does so truthfully most of the time), but use a sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect what's *actually* going over the wire.

You're obviously dealing with two different responses.

There could be several reasons for this. For one, web servers are *supposed to* respond differently depending on what `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding` headers etc.. the client sends in its request. Then there's also the possibility that the server does some kind of `User-Agent` sniffing.

Either way, capture your requests with `urllib` as well as the ones with Firefox using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and first compare the requests (not the headers, but the actual `GET / HTTP/1.0` part. Are they really the same? If yes, move on to comparing request headers and start manually setting the same headers for the `urllib` request until you figure out which headers make a difference.

Comment: @That1Guy If it's any consolation: Returning a `Location:` header _and_ `200 OK` is wrong as far as I know. It can be set when using `201 Created` or `202 Accepted` but, to my knowledge, never with `200`.

Comment: @That1Guy Also, unlike `urllib` the python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) module can [follow location redirects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) (by default it does for `GET` but not for `POST`). Not sure how it would handle `Location` + `200` though.